# How to stop iMovie removing high frequency audio when exporting?

Tags: audio, imovie

i have inserted a high frequency audio (more than 18000Hz) into a Movie, it is to test if children can hear that frequency during my video presentation. However, iMovie does not allow anything above a certain frequency to be exported.

I have tried exporting as Quicktime:
I used the following sound settings

Linear PCM

but when i click on preview and use a sound analyzer, it still doesn't detect the frequency.

Someone please help

Comment: which version of iMovie?

Comment: iMovie '11 is the current one i'm using